# Problem compiling!!! setup-di-compile yields segmentation error Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1.3, setup-di-compile

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 18.0 MiProxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 22.0 MiRepositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 22.0 MiB
Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean' not found in /home/oneupkey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Boolean.php on line 14
Segmentation fault
```

Look at this...

I'm hosting with **siteground**. They said I need to **post** here or talk to devs.  AFAIK this is a default base install...

Comment: Does the following file exist for you? `/home/oneupkey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Boolean.php`

If not you should be able to retrieve it via https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.3/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Boolean.php

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2880

Comment: Yes, that file DOES exist.